# Open PDF link in Device Browser - Flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf

I try to open url link with "url_launcer" plugin to show pdf file but Chrome show "Cannot display PDF (pdf-file-name.pdf cannot be opened)" notification. I can open link manually in emulator, but I cannot open with url_launcer's launch method.

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1440], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)

Code:

```
await launch("https://test.com/getPdf/4b5f-4118-a7dd-900cc253654c.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try out this plug in [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file)**

```html
OpenFile.open("example.pdf");
```